# Is it in line with the DCO that a github sign-off needs and publishes full name + an email "that matches the commit author"?

Tags: git, github, authorization, pull-request, git-pull

Coming from Stack Overflow where a pseudo name is normal and enough, a github beginner like me does not expect to have to sign-off a git pull request with the full name and kind of full-name-email being published. Going over to github, I simply do not expect more than what Stack Overflow is asking for. I thought the other contributors on github just chose willingly to sign with their full names and respective e-mails, and I was astonished to see my personal mail being published.

The tasks you follow to do the pull request on github (not from the DCO, this was just a helping comment):

> You need sign-off your PR with your email address. Below are steps to
> sign-off a commit. At first, you need configure your git with user
> name and email: `git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"`
> `git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"`
> Next run `git push --force-with-lease origin YOURBRANCHNAME`

I have read the DCO Developer Certificate of Origin now in the github version https://github.com/apps/dco and in the original version https://developercertificate.org/.

The github version asks for more than the original DCO, in my opinion.

> It requires all commit messages to contain the Signed-off-by line with an email address that matches the commit author.

further below...

> Contributors sign-off that they adhere to these requirements by adding a Signed-off-by line to commit messages.
> This is my commit message
>
> Signed-off-by: Random J Developer random@developer.example.org

Here you could already discuss if "Random J Developer" has to be the full name or just a pseudo name, and also whether the name (or pseudo name respectively) should be part of the mail. The original DCO speaks just generally of the personal information in the sign-off:

> I understand and agree that this project and the contribution are
> public and that a record of the contribution (including all personal
> information I submit with it, including my sign-off) is maintained
> indefinitely and may be redistributed consistent with this project or
> the open source license(s) involved.

In its intro, the github DCO mentions the email that "matches the commit author" as the core of the personal information, and later adds the name in the example. This "matches the commit author" is already a stricter requirement than the original DCO is asking for, thus this requirement could already be questioned. From the original DCO I read the option to put your full name and full name email, but not the need to do so, as the github user name and a mail that includes the github author name would be personal information enough to identify you as well, which is the main requirement. From the github DCO I read the wish that you put your full name, but it is only in the example, not in the text, and I could also go around that now by putting my github username and an email that does not show my full name but includes my github name, and still following the DCO, as I read it.

My final question after this long explanation:
Is the github DCO requirement of full name and an "email address that matches the commit author" in line with the official DCO? Or does it ask too much, and a pseudo name + email using that pseudo name would be already enough? Or as a third option, would a pseudo name + email not using any pseudo or full name already be enough?

p.s.:

To anyone of github reading this. If publishing the full name and respective email is really needed, I simply would like to be informed about this when doing my first pull request, because few people will read the DCO before starting.

Comment: This question has also been opened on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/is-it-in-line-with-the-dco-that-a-github-sign-off-needs-and-publishes-full-name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two items here which are separate and different.  One is the commit metadata which is stored in your commits, which is set with `user.name` and `user.email`.  This information is embedded by Git (not GitHub) in all commits you make so that people know who the author and committer are.

It is not required that `user.name` reflect your personal name, but it is customary.  Some projects, such as Git, strongly prefer that people use their personal name unless they are primarily known by a pseudonym, such as chromatic, the Perl contributor.  Other projects do not care.

GitHub itself does not impose any restrictions on either one (other, possibly, than that it be in UTF-8) but it does use the email address embedded in your commits (the `user.email` value) to attribute the commit to your account.  If the commit email address doesn't match any account, then it displays it as associated with the name (`user.name`) value you've specified.

In addition, some projects, such as Git, require that authors use the sign-off functionality (`git commit -s`) to intentionally state that they grant the rights to the project stated in the Developer's Certificate of Origin (or another project-specific document).  This is essentially a legal statement that the contributor has the right to contribute that code to the project.  The fact that this is a legal statement is why many projects prefer a personal name rather than a pseudonym.

When you use the `-s` (`--signoff`) option to `git commit`, Git embeds both the `user.name` and `user.email` value into the commit message as a sign-off in the format normally used inside the commit object.  A sign-off usually cannot be parsed without both.

A contributor who submits someone else's code to a project using the DCO needs to sign-off that commit.  So, for example, the Git for Windows maintainer provided me a patch which he signed off, and when I contributed it to Git, I added my sign-off, certifying that I had received it under those terms and not modified it. The Git project maintainer will sign-off the commit as well, asserting the same thing.

Thus, if you choose to add the DCO add-on to your project, it is reasonable that one of the sign-offs on the commit match an email address on your account.  Note that, as far as I'm aware, the DCO add-on doesn't require your name to match, which is reasonable: some people use a nickname or shortened form of their name, and a bit-for-bit match would be overly burdensome.

As I mentioned, GitHub doesn't require much of anything about your name and email, and technically the DCO add-on (which is a matter of project policy) does not require anything beyond a matching email.  Git will, however, embed whatever name you give it inside your commits; the only change with the DCO is that you agree that the project can maintain that indefinitely.

Comment: This answer helped me understand that the email simply must be the email that is registered at github. If I take an anonymous email as my login email on github, this already meets the requirement of an email that "matches the commit author".

Comment: Then a question was if my pseudonym is enough, and you say here that it depends, which is true. The answer in my actual case is thus no as the full name is a requirement of the project (and this is an individual thing of each project, separately, every project can set its own strict or weak rules here). This at least is the accepted answer at https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/is-it-in-line-with-the-dco-that-a-github-sign-off-needs-and-publishes-full-name, thus the two separate community answers are a full match here, both together explain the whole picture well.

Comment: I don't really want to join that community just to post a single response, but I appreciate you reaching out.

Comment: I don't want the answer to be moved or transferred there and I don't want to respond there.  Please respect that and don't push.  If it's moved or modified by a mod, I'll delete the answer and request it be purged from the site.

Answer (score 1):

This “real identity” business is mostly a cultural artifact of the Git
project and the Linux project. The Git tool itself is only mildly
opinionated about it: [1]

> `user.name`, `user.email` […] conventionally refer to some form of a
> personal name

So you would definitely have to provide your real identify if you were
to contribute to the Git project. But what the Git project’s opinion is
on this issue doesn’t matter to other projects. And it’s not like they
would have any authority even if they tried to assert it.

The documentation for “sign off” is also very unopinionated: [2] [3]

> The meaning of a signoff depends on the project to which you’re
> committing.

It doesn’t even mention a “Developer’s Certificate of Origin”.

Further, what the “Developer’s Certificiate of Origin” *is* might also
vary. It might be neatly defined as a text file in the Git or the Linux
projects, but are those the “original” ones? Well, does it matter?

What’s nice about the “sign-off” feature is that it’s not some built-in,
embedded-in-the-commit-object thing. It’s something that you have to add
to every commit message. Which also means (in my opinion) that it’s not
some global thing to enable everywhere; I wouldn’t “sign off” to every
little commit in every little project, because I don’t want to consent
to anything by default. So I would only add them in a project where I
have read and agreed to whatever terms they want me to agree to, whether
that’s called “Developer’s Certificate of Origin” or “Tim is The
Sovereign of This Project” (.txt).

#### What the DCO app thinks

All of the above applies to whatever this DCO app thinks or asserts: it
has no more and no less authority than the Git project, the Linux
project, or any other person or organization.

#### Notes

1. From `man git config` (Git 2.40.1)
2. From `man git commit`
3. While there is explicit support for `Signed-off-by` in git(1), the
   maintainer [considers (2013)](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqa9hui2lp.fsf@gitster.dls.corp.google.com/#t) that to be a mistake since
   it’s so project-specific